# SQLite: Importing csv with large number of columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv, import

I am just starting out with SQL and SQLite. I am aware that one can import a csv as a table by (1) creating a table with the necessary columns, (2) designating the delimiter/separator, and (3) importing the csv. However, I don't know how to achieve this when there are a large number of columns, making it an unrealistic task to define the table as in (1) above.

How can I import a csv as a table where the csv file contains 454 columns of differing data types?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the first line with the column names:

   ```
   Name;Amount;foo;...;bar
   ```
2. Replace the separators with commas, insert `CREATE TABLE xxx(` at the beginning, and `);` at the end:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE xxx(Name,Amount,foo,...,bar);
   ```
3. Execute this command.

Please note that there are no data types; all values in an imported CSV file are treated as strings.